# Python: how to store dictionary as csv file while retaining nature of variables

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

**Context**: For example, I am working with a dictionary that has keys, which are strings, and values which could be any of:

- lists/arrays of different lengths (with floating point numbers)
- PyTorch model

**Question**: How can I save this dictionary down in a file type (perhaps csv) such that the nature of each of the variables is retained?

- I am trying to do this to save results down from ML experiments
- Separation of data doesn't matter for me. For example, the training loss and testing loss can be saved in different files.

**Example code**:
This is what I am currently doing. I found the code on some other questions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

# create the dictionary
d = {'training_loss': [1.0, 2.20, 3.1, 4.0], 'testing_loss': [3, 4], 'best_hparams': {'lr': 0.1, 'hidden_units': 16}}

# convert the dictionary to csv file
a_file = open("sample.csv", "w")

writer = csv.writer(a_file)
for key, value in d.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
a_file.close()
```

**Problems**:

- This stores lists at strings, which means I would need to do some conversion code to convert it back to a list. For example, the training loss might be stored as '[1.0, 2.20, 3.1, 4.0]'. However, this isn't feasible as there are many types of lists entries (lists, arrays, pytorch tensors) I am working with, so forming rules for each of them would take a while.

**My ideas**:

- Should I could create data frames for each key in the dictionary corresponding to a list/array? I could do it in an iterative fashion? Perhaps it could start by checking the type of the value in the dictionary, and if it is a list, then make it a one-column dataframe. Then each dataframe could be converted into a csv file? The separation of data into separate dataframes (e.g. one for training loss, another for testing_loss, etc.) is not an issue for me.
- The bullet point above deals with the lists/arrays, but how could I deal with the values which are themselves dictionaries? If those are just hyper-parameter values (i.e. don't need to have them in a numerical version), then I can use the code in my original post? I am okay with these being stored as strings.
- Finally, how would I deal with the PyTorch models? Do I need to look into how to save them down?

Thanks

[EDIT]: I am open to using other data-types as well, not just CSV. JSON has been mentioned in the comments below, so I will look into that, but also happy to hear any other appropriate suggestions.

Comment: why do you choose csv format? why not other data storage such as json?

Comment: Why not just save it as JSON? This will preserve your variable types, and is easy to read in using either  `pandas` or the stock `json` module.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses. I was just about to edit the question and say that I am open to other data types as well. Do you both think I ought to use JSON? I haven't used that before, so will look into it

Comment: JSON and CSV are for sharing between systems that mostly don't care about each other, and they're for sharing relatively simple data at that. If you just want to back up something for yourself, go with Python's pickle module, as adang1345 pointed out below.

Comment: XML, JSON or Pickle are your best bet for a dict that has variable data values. CSV is better for 1:1 type data and cannot store variable length data well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, which can be used to save a Python object to a file and load it back later as a Python object.

Comment: i agree with adang cause pickle ca help you avoid of changing of datatype

Comment: Many thanks, I have started using pickle right now and it seems to be working. I'll accept the answer in a bit after I play around a bit with it to see if there is anything I run into. Other than the PyTorch model, everything else was stored; I just saved the PyTorch model the way pytorch suggests in the tutorial.